# Why am I getting an error saying variable not defined?

Tags: python

I am using the following code which is defining variables within a dictionary from the string content of various text files that have a similar naming convention:

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request
import json

myurls2 = {}
for x in range(1, 15):
    for y in range(1, 87):

        strvar1 = "%s" % (x)
        strvar2 = "%s" % (y)

        with open("C:\\Python33\\NASDAQ Stock Strings\\NASDAQ_Config_File_{}_{}.txt".format(x,y),"r") as f:
            myurls2[x,y] = f.read().replace('\n', '')            
            #print("myurls_" + str(strvar1) + "_" + str(strvar2) + "=", myurls[x,y])
            #print(myurls2[x,y])

            def myglob():
                global myurls2

                URLS = [myurls2[1,1]]

# Retrieve a single page and report the url and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    conn = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout)
    return conn.readall()


# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
```

The `concurrent.futures` Python module uses parallel processing to submit multiple URLs at the same time. I am just using one of my define dictionary values here to test the code but am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\test2.py", line 35, in <module>
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
NameError: name 'URLS' is not defined
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `URLS` is local to `myglob`..

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks for replying. I am quite new to Python. What syntax should I use to correct that?

Comment: There are several different ways I can read it, especially since `myglob` isn't even invoked. Maybe using `URLS` later (or at all) is just not needed and `myurls2` is sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just `return` the variable from `myglob`:

```
def myglob():
    global myurls2  # Also, never do global declarations. Ever.
    return [myurls2[1,1]]
```

Then we can get that value when we call that function, although you never seem to invoke it in your code:

```
URLS = myglob()
```

However it is noteworthy that that function is pointless, seeing as it takes no arguments- not to mention that it is never called. I think that just doing `URLS = [myurls2[1,1]]` outside of a function (within your `with` statement) would make things way simpler.

Comment: Hi again, yes you are right I think I have tried adding a solution to something that was not initially the problem when an earlier draft of this code was not working. Thanks.

Comment: Also, rather than typing URLS = [myurls2[1,1],myurls2[1,2] >>> ETC >>> myurls[14,86]], is there a way I could define everything stored within the dictionary (i.e. something like URLS = [x,y]])?

Comment: @user3045351 I don't know, but it will definitely be possible. You will be more likely to get an expert answer by asking a new question.